# Azure AD Consent from a different Tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, user-permissions, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to use our multi tenant AD application to access the user's Onedrive for Business. But I keep getting an error when consenting regarding some permissions when the user belongs from a different Tenant. I am not sure which permissions i need to set so that any 365 users can.

I am using the graph API permissions and AD that read the directory. This is what the permissions look like.

**Application permissions**

- Read files in all site collection
- Read and write files in all site collections
- Read and write devices
- Read and Write directory data
  -Read directory data

**Delegated permissions**

- Have full access to all files user can access
- Read all files that user can access
- Have full access to user files
- Read user files Access directory as the signed in user
- Read and write directory data
- Read directory data Sign in and read user profile
- Read and write files that the user selects (preview)
- Read files that the user selects (preview)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An administrator in the other tenant must consent for the app for the first time.

This is because you are using some scopes that require administrative consent.  If you restrict yourself to only scopes that do not require admin consent, then regular users should normally be able to consent directly to your app.

One thing to note, an administrator in the other tenant can always disable end-user consent in which case they would always require admin consent for every app.

Comment: Thanks, i was hoping if was something i could fix. Is there any other options to using O365 accounts and having access to their Onedrive , maybe using Azure B2C or is it always based on the other tenants app permissions?

Comment: Well, B2C won't work. The v2 endpoint might help, but I'll have to test it quickly to see if it was possible for a user to consent for themselves.

Comment: Thanks to @GarethJ for fixing my misconception here. Guess I had only used perms requiring admin/had disabled the setting allowing users to consent. So yeah, it depends on the permissions you require. The delegated Files.Read ("Read user files") permission does not require admin, so that should be possible. You can't use app permissions though, those do require an admin to consent always.

Comment: While there are exceptions, a good general rule of thumb is if the scope/permission includes the word `All` it will most likely require Admin Consent. A user can typically access their own information without consent whereas accessing other user's data requires an Admin to give a thumbs up. :)

Comment: Yeah that's the rule of thumb, though it is up to the person defining the permissions ;)

Comment: Thanks, removing all the Admin required permissions works.

Comment: Awesome! Good to hear :)